# Laravel 4 Authentication: Reminders Controller - GET reset not found

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4's built in password reminder feature in a new application. It seems that the code it's generating and what the docs are saying is either incomplete, inconsistent, or I'm missing a vital point.

So far, I have...

1. Created Reminder Table
2. Migrated it
3. Created Reminder Controller
4. Tested both get / post for `password/remind`, successfully.

Where I am stuck is with the reset methods of the controller. The reminder url successfully sends to my email and once I click it, I get a `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException` error.

The url that the `Password::remind` static method sends to my email is `http://localhost/application/public/password/reset/3e5e7a5c8562b28909b9948e848c5692dccb4f8a`.

**My GET / POST reset methods in the reminder controller -**

```
    public function getReset($token = null)
    {
        if (is_null($token)) App::abort(404);

        return View::make('password.reset')->with('token', $token);
    }

    public function postReset()
    {
        $credentials = Input::only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );

        $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
        {
            $user->password = Hash::make($password);

            $user->save();
        });

        switch ($response)
        {
            case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
            case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }
```

**My password/reset.blade.php file -**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'password/reset')) }}
  {{ Form::hidden('token', $token) }}
  {{ Form::email('email', null, array('class'=>'', 'placeholder'=>'Email Address')) }}
  {{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'', 'placeholder'=>'Password')) }}
  {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class'=>'', 'placeholder'=>'Password Confirmation')) }}

  {{ Form::submit('Reset Password', array('class'=>'')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Anyone have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong??

Comment: what are your routes, does `Route::get('password/reset/{token}')` exist?

Comment: Sans {token}, yes. That's probably it. The docs don't hint at that but I see now how that is implicit. Let me test it when I'm back at my machine. Want to post it as an answer, if that in fact fixes it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your most likely missing some routes add these if they don't already exist.

`Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'RemindersController@getReset');`

It is also likely that you will need the reset `post` route as well.

`Route::post('password/reset/{token}', 'RemindersController@postReset');`

Comment: I was missing {token}! Thanks a lot, Kyle

Comment: @CasBloem Something is not wrong, simply because it's different to your approach at solving the issue. You should also check the date it was posted, since frameworks change a lot in 9 months.

Comment: Did I miss something? Who's @CasBloem?

Comment: @Seth He commented saying this answer was wrong, however it seems he has changed his mind now.